# IFERROR formula contain with average and divide function

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to turn those error value to blank but seems the formula below doesn't work.'

=IFERROR(H58-AVERAGE(H20,H24,H16,H12,H35,H47,H43,H39,H8,H31,H54),"")/IFERROR(AVERAGE(H20,H24,H16,H12,H35,H47,H43,H39,H8,H31,H54),"")

The below is the original formula that I let the formula go Value minus average then only go for divide average but some cell still did not contain any formula, then I need to add IFERROR formula to hide the error value in the cell. Anyone can advise a better formula solution on this?

=(D53-AVERAGE(D15,D19,D11,D7,D30,D42,D38,D34,D23,D46))/AVERAGE(D15,D19,D11,D7,D30,D42,D38,D34,D23,D46)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IFERROR needs to be applied only once. Applying it separately after the divide operation could still result in a number being divided by 0, which would give an error.

```
=IFERROR((D53-AVERAGE(D15,D19,D11,D7,D30,D42,D38,D34,D23,D46))/AVERAGE(D15,D19,D11,D7,D30,D42,D38,D34,D23,D46), "")
```

In Ms365 or excel 2021, you can use `LET` to do the average calculation only once:

```
=LET(
Avg, AVERAGE(D15, D19, D11, D7, D30, D42, D38, D34, D23, D46),
IFERROR((D53-Avg)/Avg, "")
)
```

Comment: =IFERROR((D53-AVERAGE(D15,D19,D11,D7,D30,D42,D38,D34,D23,D46))/AVERAGE(D15,D19,D11,D7,D30,D42,D38,D34,D23,D46), "")

This is work for me. Thanks